# RegEx найти определенный символ перед заданным количеством символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как найти последний конкретный символ перед заданным количеством символов?

Например есть строка:

`abcabcabc`

дается число 6 и символ 'a', нужно найти последнюю 'a' стоящую до шестого символа.

`abc_bcabc`

`a(?=(\n.{.<6}))` это не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `a` может быть шестым символом, используйте

```
^(.{0,5})a
```

Замените совпадение на `$1_` / `${1}_` / `\1_` (зависит от конкретной библиотеки регулярных выражений).

См. [пример использования](https://regex101.com/r/JJSnmS/1).